# How do I get MonoDevelop 2.8 with Mono 2.10?

Tags: 11.10, repository, mono, monodevelop

After some research I found out, that the repo provides the old version 2.6 of the MonoDevelop IDE, but as there is already the latest version published I want to know whether someone knows how I can install it (there is no package out for Ubuntu 11.10) without messing up my current system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the version of monodevelop installed through Ubuntu's software sources, download the source code archive for monodevelop 2.8 upstream (http://monodevelop.com/Download), and build and install the source manually. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo for general advice on building software from source.

Comment: For those who experience installation problems like me - this one helped me a lot [Config Problems](http://askubuntu.com/q/74062/23607)

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking around, and I found a ppa that might interest you if you have not already found a solution:

https://launchpad.net/~ermshiperete/+archive/monodevelop

I just installed it and it seems to be working alongside with 2.6 with no issues.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I came across this thread looking for this exact issue. While this was of some help, I found [this](http://chornsokun.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/build-monodevelop-on-ubuntu-11-10/) tutorial to be a great resource as well. Just wanted to share.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.