# ./configure: Mono version not recognized during MonoDevelop config

Tags: 11.10, configuration, dependencies, mono, monodevelop

I want to install MonoDevelop 2.10 and I have cloned the current release with `git clone git://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git` however running `./configure` I get the error:

```
checking for UNMANAGED_DEPENDENCIES_MONO... no
configure: error: Please install mono version 2.8 or later to install MonoDevelop.
Please see http://www.mono-project.org/ to download latest mono sources or packages
```

Although I have Ubuntu 11.10 with `Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.5 (Debian 2.10.5-1)` (output of `mono --version`) this error seems to be trolling me. Can anyone explain me, what error drives me crazy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need mono-devel installed though that may not be the end of your configure issues. Maybe just go ahead & run

```
sudo apt-get build-dep monodevelop
```

Comment: Works fine! (Just thought that the IDE should be version 2.10 and not 2.8 as Mono itself is version 2.10...)

Comment: Its 2013 and I'm still facing this very same issue on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Maybe this will change some day!!